# Logic propositions

Tags: logic

I am trying to determine if the following sentences are a proposition and A couple of the sentences are listed below any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your *attempt* to solve this yourself would be appreciated.  For a start, what is *your* definition for "a proposition"?

Comment: @GrahamKemp A statement that can either be true or false. So im pretty sure 1 is a proposition and im thinking 2 is not a proposition. However the negation part confuses me.

Comment: @Sherin you removed the sentences in your last edit, can you revert it or add the sentences again?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (A proposition is) A statement that can either be true or false. So im pretty sure 1 is a proposition and im thinking 2 is not a proposition. However the negation part confuses me.

Yes, that is it.   Sentence 1 is a proposition.

Now, because if something is neither true nor false it cannot have a negation, therefore you need only negate the proposition.